# Recover deleted AWS tags for instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to recover *tags* which were deleted from an AWS ec2 instance using a python boto3 script?

The script used the boto3 [delete_tags](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.delete_tags) method and passed an empty value for the field **TAGS**

```
response = client.delete_tags(
    Resources=['cacscas'],
    Tags=[]
)
```

I have checked the *Cloudtrail* events and it has the **delete** event but only stores the query that was passed to delete the tags, not the deleted tags. 
Neither does *Cloudwatch* have anything, I think unless you create a custom logger, cloudwatch doesn't.

Is there any other way to recover tags?

Comment: CloudTrail now has 90 days worth of logs. So, if your instance / instance tags were created in the last 90 days, you can `lookup_events()` on the instance id and the event name (RunInstances / CreateTags) to get that info. Otherwise, you can get the logs from Splunk / Sumologic (if integrated).

Comment: I realize that hindsight is 20/20, but AWS Config can be useful for tracking this kind of stuff. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/05/aws-config-provides-faster-recording-of-tag-changes-new-managed-rule-and-other-usability-improvements/

Answer (score 0):

If you have AWS Config enabled, you would be able to see the old tags. To view them, go to CloudTrail -> Expand the specific Event details (in this case DeleteTags) -> go to Config Timeline. Tag details would be shown in there. A few screenshots:

CloudTrail console:
[image: CloudTrail console]

Config timeline:
[image: Config Timeline]